# Zero diagonal matrices periodicity and bipartite graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, graph-theory, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ be a nonsymmetric zero diagonal matrix such that $A^k, k=2n+1, n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ has also zero diagonal.

Is $A$ *always* the adjacency matrix of some possibly directed, weighted (allowing negative weights) **bipartite** graph as well?

Separate question related to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394629/orbits-and-numerical-ranges-of-zero-diagonal-matrices-with-block-patterns).

Comment: Are you asking if the diagonal entries are necessarily zero? Of course not.  For instance, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&-1}
$$

Comment: No, maybe I am not making myself clear again. I am asking: provided that the diagonal entries are zero and that the diagonal entries of $A^k, k=2n+1, n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ are also zero, is the matrix and adjacency matrix? I'll modify the post to make this clear.

Comment: but isn't *every* matrix with zeros on the diagonal an adjacency matrix of a directed graph with certain weights?

Comment: It is, but does the periodicity imply that the graph is bipartite?

Comment: aha.  You said bipartite in the title, but not the body, of the question

Comment: Thanks! :P I am writing and modifying a million times, sorry!