# Products of zero diagonal matrices and spectrum symmetry

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ be a nonsymmetric zero diagonal matrix such that $A^k, k=2n+1, n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ has also zero diagonal.

Is there an easy proof or reference that the spectrum of $A$ is symmetric with respect to the imaginary axis?

Comment: Notably, $\operatorname{Tr}(A^k) = \sum_{i}\lambda_i^k$.  If this comes out to $0$ for all odd $k$, maybe we could do something using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Comment: Also, it is notable that in the complex matrix case, the real condition is symmetry with respect to the origin.  That is, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue implies that $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: There's a relevant discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397468/the-sum-of-odd-powered-complex-numbers-equals-zero-implies-they-cancel-each-othe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that $Tr(A^k)=\sum_i \lambda_i^k = 0$ for all odd $k$, the sets of complex numbers having this property cancel each other in pairs as proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397468/the-sum-of-odd-powered-complex-numbers-equals-zero-implies-they-cancel-each-othe).